# Empty cells issue when extracting excel data using POI in JAVA?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, jexcelapi

I have just Extracted the cells from the excel sheet using Apache POI, everything is working fine. But whenever there is an empty cell, the very next right cell data is what I get as a output. But, if exists a value in the latter, the desired output is coming.

This is the logic I've written.

```
    Iterator<Row> rowIterator=sheet.rowIterator();
    while(rowIterator.hasNext())
    {

        ExtractedRowsString extRows=new ExtractedRowsString();
        ArrayList<HSSFCell> list=new ArrayList<HSSFCell>();
        HSSFRow row=(HSSFRow) rowIterator.next();

        Iterator<Cell> cellIterator=row.cellIterator();
        while(cellIterator.hasNext())
        {
            HSSFCell cell=(HSSFCell)cellIterator.next();
            list.add(cell); 
        }
        if(check)
        {
            addBean(list,extRows);
            print(extRows);
        }

        check=true;

    }
```

What may be the problem?

**EDITED :**

```
public static void addBean(ArrayList list,ExtractedRowsString extRows)
{
    for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
    {
        switch(i)
        {
            case 0:
                extRows.setSchool_success_id((list.get(i)).toString());
                break;
            case 1:
                extRows.setPem_id( (list.get(i)).toString() );
                break;  
            case 2:
                extRows.setDistrict_code((list.get(i)).toString());
                break;
            case 3:
                extRows.setDistrict((list.get(i)).toString());
                break;

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [docs](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFRow.html#cellIterator()):

> **cellIterator**
>
> *public java.util.Iterator cellIterator()*
>
> Specified by:
>   cellIterator in interface Row
>
> Returns:
>   cell iterator of the physically
>   defined cells. Note that the 4th
>   element might well not be cell 4, as
>   the iterator will not return
>   un-defined (null) cells. Call
>   getCellNum() on the returned cells to
>   know which cell they are. As this only
>   ever works on physically defined
>   cells, the Row.MissingCellPolicy has
>   no effect.

In short, empty cells do not show up in the iterator so you always have to check which cell you got.

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList does permit adding nulls. Also what is the addBean method doing (skipping nulls or empty strings perhaps?) Can you post a small working code that one can run ?

Comment: Calm, i've added my add bean method.